# How to display QGIS "processing ..." bar from a plugin?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gui

QGIS seems to have an integrated animation which purpose is to tell the user "Please wait, I am not freezing, I am processing"

[image: loading bar in GUI]
[image: QGIS loading bar]

What is especially cool about it is that it is perfectly integrated to QGIS GUI (docked in the bottom) and doesn't fill itself like a QProgressBar : it just bounces from one side to another, giving no informations about the progression, just saying "Wait, I am processing".

I would like to know if it is possible to call this bar from a plugin.

I know of alternate options, which are displaying a QProgressBar (in my plugin gui or in a QMessageBar). 
I even found [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158653/how-to-add-loading-bar-in-qgis-plugin-development), which seemed to ask the same question I am asking but ended accepting "Display a standard QProgressBar in a QMessageBar" as an answer. And this isn't what I want.

I am not considering options on how to tell my user to wait. I would like to know if there is a way to call this specific bar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create bar:

```
bar = QProgressBar()
```

Set range from 0 to 0:

```
bar.setRange(0,0)
```

And now you have:
[image]

Just set normal values like (0,100) if you want to end this "busy" state.

If you want to place this bar in that place, you have to add it to this object:

```
iface.mainWindow().statusBar().addWidget(bar)
```

Here is a documentation and you can find more informations about that: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html

Comment: Thanks, that solves the most important part of my problem. This creates a bar that indicates "busy" state the way I want to. 

Still, I'd like to know if this bar could be docked the way the one QGIS uses is. (See the picture I added to my question to make it clearer)

If I end up not finding how to do so, I'd accept your answer !

Comment: You can get access to this object with: `iface.mainWindow().statusBar()`. I'm going to edit my post with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Quick note for anyone who would like to put the bar exactly where QGIS does (like in the picture in the question) : 
The syntax is :
iface.mainWindow().statusBar().insertPermanentWidget(0, bar)
(It can be found in the documentation dmh126 linked)